# How to select tab automatically after form submission using jeasyui

Tags: php

I want to be able to automatically select the tab with title "Search For Books" and display the results in the with id results. This should happen after submission of the form with id endesa.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../demo.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="easyui-tabs" style="width:700px;height:250px">
<div title="About" style="padding:10px">
<p style="font-size:14px">
jQuery EasyUI framework help you build your web page easily.  
</p>contesnts
</div>
<div title="Search For Books" style="padding:10px">
<form action="mysql.php" method="post" id="endesa">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" name="button" value="Search"/>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
<div title="Help" data-options="iconCls:'icon-help',closable:true" style="padding:10px">
his is the help content.
</div>
</div></body>
```

Comment: Where is your `<body>` tag?

Comment: The body should be before this tag here <div class="easyui-tabs" style="width:700px;height:250px"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `autofocus` attribute to the input.

`<input id="search" type="text" autofocus>`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FrqJy/)**

Comment: I want to select a tab with this form id id="endesa" i m using jeasyui